# In C, is there a better way to calculate uncertainty values?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

What I've been doing is using a `#define UNC` (uncertainty) to toggle on and off the functionality for calculating `x` (the value) and `dx` (the uncertainty). It works pretty well, but it's not easy to read or write. is there a better way to do this? In C++ I might use `std::pair`, or maybe some sort of tuple. I could also use a struct with both `x` and `dx`, and sometimes leave `dx` undefined, but *I plan on running this code at very large scales* and don't want it slowing down the compiler by processing all these unnecessary items once `UNC` is turned off.

Have any of you come across a similar problem?

Here's the code, for reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define UNC

typedef struct{
    double x;
#ifdef UNC
    double dx;
#endif
    } Foo;

int force(Foo* m, Foo* a, Foo* f){
    f->x = m->x * a->x;
#ifdef UNC
    f->dx = (f->x)*(m->dx/m->x + a->dx/a->x);
#endif
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    Foo m; m.x = 3.0;
    Foo a; a.x = 2.0;
#ifdef UNC
    m.dx = 0.3;
    a.dx = 0.2;
#endif
    Foo f;
    force(&m,&a,&f);
    printf(" f is %f \n", f.x);
#ifdef UNC
    printf("df is %f \n", f.dx);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To avoid solving a problem which does not exist, have you measured and inferred that the computation of `dx` is indeed a bottleneck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define some macros as follows, which would neaten things up....

```
#ifdef UNC
    #define SetDx(f, v) (f)->dx = (v)
    #define PRINT_UNC(x) printf x
#else
    #define SetDx(f, v)
    #define PRINT_UNC(x)
#endif
```

Then write your code as

```
int force(Foo* m, Foo* a, Foo* f){
    f->x = m->x * a->x;
    SetDx(f, (f->x)*(m->dx/m->x + a->dx/a->x));
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    Foo m; m.x = 3.0;
    Foo a; a.x = 2.0;
    SetDx(&m, 0.3);
    SetDx(&a, 0.2);

    Foo f;
    force(&m,&a,&f);
    printf(" f is %f \n", f.x);
    PRINT_UNC(("df is %f \n", f.dx));
    return 0;
}
```

This way you can minimise the number of #ifdef block in your code, which make things difficult to read. When you turn of the main define, the `SetDx` and `PRINT_UNC` macros will do nothing. (Note the need to double brackets in the `PRINT_UNC` macro).

Just a quick question about the part of your question that says:

> ...slowing down the compiler by processing all these unnecessary items
>   once UNC is turned off...

Are you worried about the pre-processing speed? I though this sounded like you might be worrying that the compiler was taking time *compiling* the ifdef as a kind of switch... if that's the case, don't worry, the pre-processor kills the undefined blocks so the compiler never sees them. If you're worried about pre-processing speed, there's not a lot you can do I don't think, but I wouldn't have thought the pre-processing overhead would be significant?